# window.onload called after returning from a event handler method

Tags: javascript

This code is for learning purpose in javascript.I have declared a global variable called num and initialized it to 30. Now this is increased on click of a plus button and is decreased on click of minus button.But when I click plus button twice.It alerts 31 twice instead of showing 31 first then 32.

When I debugged it on chrome I found out that the breakpoint hits 'var num=30' again once it executes the increase method which is called onclick of plus button.
So why after the return from method the window is reloading?Can someone please explain?Thanks in advance.My code is as below :

```
window.onload =initialize;
var num=30;
function initialize()
{

if(!document.getElementById) return;

var increaseButton = document.getElementById('plus');
increaseButton.onclick = increase;
var decreaseButton = document.getElementById('minus');
decreaseButton.onclick = decrease;
 }

function increase()
 {
    num++;
    alert(num);

 }
function decrease()
 {
     num++;
     alert(num);
 }
```

Comment: After I step over after the end braces of increase() code flow goes right to the top to window.onload =initialize;  I also checked the value of num at that time was undefined.

Comment: sounds like your button is a submit button

Comment: @HarshKrishna — Your description of the problem suggests that you are wrong about that. Try providing a [MCVE] **including the HTML**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me if the HTML is:

```
<button type="button" id="plus">+</button>
<button type="button" id="minus">-</button>
```

You would also want your decrease function to be:

```
function decrease()
{
    num--;
    alert(num);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/OzymandiasII/L9h1xbsr/

Comment: thanks Ozymandias...it worked...I didnt used type attribute on button tag before.